# Colvis exclude columns dynamically from an external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to the jQuery datatable. Using Colvis API option

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        colVis: {
            exclude: [ 0,1 ]
        }
    } );
```

So it seems that we have an option in the datatable configuration to exclude columns in the Show / Hide dropdown.

Ref: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/examples/exclude_columns.html

But i need to your help on how to accomplish this functionality by using an externally. So i can remove / add columns in the dropdown list dynamically.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: very simple mate just you need to use colVis plugin and later include `C` in sdom and and try columns you want to ignore and later hide/show remaining column's dynamically and go on .

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
      "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',

        "oColVis": {
        "exclude": [0,1,2,3]
       }
    }
} );
```

And use datatable 1.10.